# Regex matches a wrong value

Tags: regex

```
/^(?:(?:x[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]+(?:\.?[0-9]{1,2})?)|(?:[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]{1,2})?))(?:\/x[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]+(?:\.?[0-9]{1,2})?)*$/
```

Hello,
my regex should match:

`5
40.33
23.50/x4:50.22
11/x2:50/x4:68/x6:102.48`

I try to describe... There are unlimited blocks seperated by "/". The first block is always just a float value. All other blocks are starting with "x[0-9]+:" and then the float value.

But my regex also matches:

```
40/50
```

?

Comment: could you give more examples of what should and shouldn't be matched?

Comment: `40/50` is matched because of `(?:(?:x[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]+(?:\.?[0-9]{1,2})?)|(?:[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]{1,2})?))`. You forgot to escape the dot near `(?:.[0-9]`. The dot matches any character but a newline.

Comment: yes, "5" and "40.33" should match.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xN8jO3/1

Comment: Oh, thats it. Thank you very much @Wiktor

Comment: looks like its under control ;)

Comment: And thank you @georg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`40/50` is matched because of `(?:(?:x[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]+(?:\.?[0-9]{1,2})?)|(?:[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]{1,2})?))`. You forgot to escape the dot near `(?:.[0-9]`. The dot matches any character but a newline.